When creating polygon fill symbols in GeoServer, how do I configure the initial position offset for the fill pattern?
I would like to create a surface fill symbol system which consists of three layers. The first layer is a solid fill; the second layer is a graphic fill; and the third layer is a duplicate of the second layer's graphic fill. The desired final effect is depicted in the following image.

As shown in the figure, the initial positioning of the first graphic fill layer and the second graphic fill layer is staggered, forming a diamond-shaped filling pattern. However, I have only found in the official documentation the tag for configuring blank space around the symbol, which is <se:VendorOption name="graphic-margin">, but I haven't found how to apply an offset; After exporting the symbol system from QGIS to SLD, I noticed there is a Displacement tag in the SLD, however, this tag does not seem to be taking effect.I am wondering how to create such a symbol?
help me please
Supplementary Information
The symbol I have implemented is as follows, as shown in the attached image.

The SLD XML as below.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>p6_治理恢复</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>p6_治理恢复</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
<se:Rule>
          <se:Name>耕地恢复</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>耕地恢复</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>zlhfcs</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>耕地恢复</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d9ad00</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Cartography#0xc8</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#70a800</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>10</se:Size>
                  <se:Displacement>
                    <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
                    <se:DisplacementY>0</se:DisplacementY>
                  </se:Displacement>                  
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="graphic-margin">10 10</se:VendorOption>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:GraphicFill>
                <se:Graphic>
                  <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>ttf://ESRI Cartography#0xc8</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Fill>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#70a800</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Fill>
                  </se:Mark>       
                  <se:Size>10</se:Size>
                  <se:Displacement>
                    <se:DisplacementX>50</se:DisplacementX>
                    <se:DisplacementY>50</se:DisplacementY>
                  </se:Displacement>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:VendorOption name="graphic-margin">11 9</se:VendorOption>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
          </se:Rule>

